# Jquery dynamically populating a select option tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to achieve something like this,

```
<select id="time" size="1" name="Time" disabled="disabled">
    <% foreach (string item in (List<string>)Model.OpenCloseTime[dynamicVariable].AppointmentTimes)
        {%>
            <option id="<%:item%>" value="<%:item%>">
            <%:item%></option>
        <%} 
    %>
</select>
```

Where `dynamicVariable= $('#date').datepicker("getDate");`

To break down the issue, getDate is supposed to fetch the value of the weekday from a calendar which needs to help me dynamically populate a select dropdown, based on the data we are getting from the model object day value.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you saying you wish a jQuery solution to the presented ASPX code?

Comment: yes, I need to achieve this dynamically through jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `dynamicVariable` looks like, but here's how you can populate `#time` with a Javascript array:

```
var times = ["Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening"];
for(i in times) {
    $("#time").append(
        $("<option></option>").attr("value", times[i]).text(times[i])
    );
}
```

**Edit to answer your comment:**

Concatenate your list:

```
List<string> items = (List<string>)Model.OpenCloseTime[dynamicVariable].AppointmentTimes;
string itemsStr = string.Join(",", items.toArray());
```

Print it in your javascript:

```
var items = "<%:itemStr%>";
```

Explode the string into a Javascript array:

```
var items_arr = items.split(",");
```

Use what I posted above to make the select box:

```
for(i in items_arr) {
    $("#time").append(
        $("<option></option>").attr("value", items_arr[i]).text(items_arr[i])
    );
}
```

Comment: And of course you can replace the `for` with a jQuery `$.each`

Comment: My issue is that the dynamicVariable is supposed to be the int value that will act as index value for my Model Object to retrieve the specific List<strings>, which is then will be used to populate the select tag.

Comment: You're going to have to concatenate your List<string> into a comma-delimited string then use more Javascript logic to parse it.  Javascript can't read your ASPX code straight like that.

Comment: I updated my answer with how you can go about doing my solution.

Comment: Be careful with this.  You'll have issues if any of your values in the items list already have commas.  I would suggest using ajax to return the list as json if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is and example of populating a select list using jQuery:

```
function setCategory(categoryList)
{
    var options = '<option value="Select by Category">Select by Category</option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++)
    {
        options += '<option value="' + categoryList[i] + '">' + categoryList[i] + '</option>';
    };
    $("#categorySelect").html(options);
};
```

Note, THIS also sets a default text using the first line, which may not be a desire here.